# Does threading work, when external applications block each other?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two raspberry pi´s uploading content to a webpage from the same router, which occasionally makes them block access for each other. To prevent this in java, you would normally use threads and synchronize, wait/notify and all that - but how can you do that, when the applications don´t know about each others excistens? -
My code looks something like that - and works otherwise as expected.

```
public void sendStrings(String output) {
    String url2 = "http://myhomepage.com";

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {

        URL obj = new URL(url2);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(output);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String otherLine;

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {

        connection.disconnect();

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that they use the same router or not. Synchronization between multiple clients is handled by the server, the clients do not care about it.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do to avoid it?

Comment: Two devices on the same network should not "block each other," ever.  Unless the server is busy, and then the number of devices doesn't matter.  Your question makes no sense to me, I think you have to discover what your real problem is.

Comment: "blocking" means that the threads are* using synchronization in some way - like both threads call obj.Lock() - one gets to run, the other blocks. When two threads don't do that, they don't block - and the result is typically a race condition and unpredictable results. A router is not involved in synchronization across devices. If there is any sort of blocking going on here it would be on the server side.